# Where can I get the full api doc of rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

It seems http://api.rubyonrails.org/ is not for rails 3. Where can I get the api doc of rails 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the docs online on http://apidock.com/rails or you can generate your local documentation using:

```
rake doc:rails
```

Comment: The website is really good. It makes the search very easy and fast, and it just uses Javascript!

Comment: railsapi.com no longer seem to work. Updated answer to another site providing Rails docs.

Comment: apidock doesn't work for me, it's loading really slowly and it's not able to switch between different versions of rails.

Answer (score 3):

It can also be found at http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/. You can change **v3.2.16** to access a particular version (Eg. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/). I could not find any index for older versions.

Comment: wish they would advertise this fact!